Create a C++ inherited class usable in Blueprint in Unreal Engine
I have a CPP interface with several virtual functions that i can find in my Blueprint project thanks to "UINTERFACE(BlueprintType)" :
UINTERFACE(BlueprintType)
class UFLoop_ConditionalBloc : public UFBloc {
    GENERATED_BODY()
public: 
    virtual ~UFLoop_ConditionalBloc() = default;
};

class IFLoop_ConditionalBloc : public IFBloc
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:

    virtual void Initialize() const = 0;
    virtual void Update() const = 0;

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<UFBloc> action;
};

I also have a class inheriting from this one, but it doesn't has "UCLASS(BlueprintType) and doesn't inherit from "UObject", so I can't find it in Blueprint :

class WhileBloc : public IFLoop_ConditionalBloc {
private:
    std::function<bool()> condition;
    std::unique_ptr<UFBloc> action;

public:
    WhileBloc(std::function<bool()> cond, std::unique_ptr<UFBloc> act)
        : condition(cond), action(std::move(act)) {}

    void Execute() const override {
        // implementation of my function
    }
};

I want to know how to make it inherit from "IFLoop_ConditionalBloc", to override its functions, but also from "UObject", to be able to find it in Blueprint
When i try to do this :
UCLASS(BlueprintType)
class UWhileBloc : public UObject, public IFLoop_ConditionalBloc {

I have this error : "Class marked by UCLASS must inherit only one class derived from UObject or UObject directly"
What is the best way to get a class that inherits from another available in Blueprint ?

And you're certain that IFBloc doesn't inherit from UObject? The error message seems to indicate that it does.
